# Using Jasmine.js Warning:boot is not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm using Jasmine 1.3 with RequireJS and Grunt. I have a grunt task that does this:

```
jasmine: {
        app: {
            options: {
                outfile: "<%= config.testPath() %>/jasmine_runner/_SpecRunner.html",
                specs: ["<%= config.testPath() %>/specs/*Spec.js"],
                template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
                templateOptions:{
                    requireConfigFile: ['<%= config.appPath() %>/js/config.js','<%= config.testPath() %>/specs/testConfig.js']
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

From the command line, I execute grunt jasmine which gives this error:

```
Running "jasmine:app" (jasmine) task
Warning: boot is not defined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

PhantomJS is set up to run it in the background. I have done extensive search on what the boot error means but haven't found anything.

Comment: see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/pull/112

Comment: I am having the same problem. Been searching for two days to get it fixed.

Comment: @pelachile did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your version of `grunt-contrib-jasmine`.

Upgrading from `0.5.1` to `0.7.0` fixed this issue for me.

Here's my package.json for reference:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "matchdep": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "~0.2.0"
  },
  ...
}
```